# jQuery navigation browser address bar

Tags: php, jquery

I have a website which dynamically loads the content in a div container using jQuery load function.
In the browser address line is always: http://www.meinedomain.de/#

Now I would have semantic URLs in the browser address bar.
For example: meinedomain.de/impressum

Do I open http://www.meinedomain.de/impressum I see only the content of impressum.php. Header, Navigation, Footer etc. missing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".freizeitparks").click(function() {
        hideMainContent();
        $('#pagecontainer').load('freizeitparks.html');
        $('#contentTitle').html("<strong>Freizeitparks</strong>");
    });
```

I hope you can help me.

Best regards
Patrick

Comment: Can you post the content of the PHP file? Perhaps something is wrong there.

Comment: You have to use HTML5 History API if you want to change the url without reloading the full page. You have to include your footer, header, etc. in impressum.php and make a decision tree when you access the site with ajax. My trick is I pass a get parameter  when I use ajax so I know when it should return the whole page or just part of it.

Comment: @I3B13 please write an answer with this: it is the correct answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use HTML5 History API if you want to change the url without reloading the full page.

With the History API you can only catch when the browser history changed and the base url is still the same site. That means when they use the address bar to open up a url like http://www.meinedomain.de/impressum it's gonna send a request to the site no matter what you do. So you have to include your footer, header, etc. in `impressum.php`.

But because you can catch the change of the browser history (back, forward, go, etc.) you can use ajax calls to load data dynamically. Use the API to change the URL and send an ajax call instead reloading everything. On backend you have to make a decision tree to catch when it was called with ajax or not. (My trick is I pass a get parameter when I use ajax so I know when it should return the whole page or just part of it.)

You can also keep continue to use the hash method but then you have to use a workaround to let searchengines to map your site. And don't forget to check the hash on load and not use only on hashchange.

Maybe that's all.

Comment: Just another question: When I catch the GET parameter in the content file and it has "isAjax" in it I echo the whole "<div>blabla</div>" otherwise I have to echo the whole head, body tag and so on. Is it a "good" solution or is there a better solution? When I have changes of the content do I really have to edit both parts?

Comment: The trick here you echo the head tag, header, footer etc. when `!isAjax`. For example `if(!isset($_GET['isAjax'])){ HEAD } YOUR CONTENT` so you have to edit only there. Of course it's better to require the head and other parts or just exit the php and open when needed instead of echo long static text.